# How to store pem file in database and retrieve back and use as pem file

Tags: php, mysql, pem

I have many pem files for different APNS auth. Now I want to store the pem files into database and retrieve it as pem.

I have tried using this header

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-pem-file');
```

but it's not working, please help.

Comment: Store paths to the .pem files in your database, not the actual .pem file.

Comment: I don't want to keep the pem files and that is why I need to store in database. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: If you really want the whole file in the database then paste the content into the database and then generate the pem-file!

Comment: You're either keeping the .pem files on a server or in the dattabase. What is the difference?

Comment: Just wanted to save in database, and I tried generating pem file using php but didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think BLOB datatype might be useful. Please refer to this link 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html
Hope it helps

Comment: How to store and retrieve back with php ?

Comment: go through link http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx